# Miss Appropriation Mission - not dropping the evidence dossier

Tags: grand-theft-auto-san-andreas

I'm playing GTA San Andreas "Miss Appropriation" mission. I’ve followed the walkthrough, get out of the helicopter, kill the agent, and it says now collect the evidence dossier before any one else does. But there isn’t anything for me to collect. I walk over the guy who I’ve killed, around him… everywhere. There isn’t anything so the mission doesn’t complete. It’s driving me insane. I’ve tried at least 20 times and it’s the same thing.

Please does anyone know what I can do?

Comment: Weird question but have you tried SilentPatch? (https://gtaforums.com/topic/669045-silentpatch/) It's a mod that fixed a lot of issues with GTA San Andreas.